# Convert SGML to XML with regex?

Tags: java, regex, xml

I want to convert SGML to XML with regrex. Like:

convert:

```
<a><ab><abc>111<abc2>222</ab></a>
```

to:

```
<a><ab><abc>111</abc><abc2>222</abc2></ab></a>
```

And I write the following code to do the conversion:

```
String a = "<a><ab><abc>abc<abc2>abc2</ab></a>";
a = a.replaceAll("<([^<>]+?)>([^<>]+?)<(?!/\\$1>)", "<$1>$2</$1><");
System.out.println(a);
```

However the result is not the expected one:

```
<a><ab><abc>111</abc><abc2>222</ab></a>
```

My question, is it possible to do the conversion with regex? If yes, What's the issue in my code?

Comment: Highly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1451599

Comment: @dirkk I got cancer after reading that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below regex

```
<(([^<>]+?)>)([^<>]+?)(?=<(?!\1))
```

And then replace the match with

```
<$1$3</$2>
```

https://regex101.com/r/cD1nC8/1

```
String s = "<a><ab><abc>111<abc2>222</ab></a>";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("<(([^<>]+?)>)([^<>]+?)(?=<(?!\\1))", "<$1$3</$2>"));
```

Output:

```
<a><ab><abc>111</abc><abc2>222</abc2></ab></a>
```

Comment: `\\$` matches a literal `$` symbol. add a extra capturing group to capture the trailing `>` symbol.

Comment: I got trouble again when dealing with multilines. https://regex101.com/r/cD1nC8/4